# In a $k$-connected graph for every two paths contain only the initial vertex

Tags: graph-theory

If G is a $k$-connected graph and $u,v_1,v_2, \dots , v_t$ are $t+1$ distinct vertices in $G$ for $2 \leq t \leq k$, $G$ contains a $u-v_i$ path for each $1 \leq i \leq t$, every two paths of which have only $u$ in common.

I believe the result comes from Whitney's theorem but how to show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We construct a new graph $G'$ by adding a new vertex $w$ and adding $t$ new edges $(w, v_1)$, $(w, v_2)$, $\cdots$, and $(w, v_t)$ to $G$. The resulting graph $G'$ is $t$-connected. By the [Menger's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem#Vertex_connectivity), there exist $t$ vertex-disjoint paths from $u$ to $w$ in $G'$. Note any path from $u$ to $w$ must pass one of $\{v_1, \cdots, v_t\}$. Therefore, the $t$ vertex-disjoint paths from $u$ to $w$ correspond to $t$-vertex disjoint paths from $u$ to $\{v_1, \cdots, v_t\}$ respectively.

Comment: Do you mean after adding vertex $w$ then $t=k$ so there exists $t$ internally disjoint paths ? isn't that whiteny's theorem which can be provedby menger's theorem ?

Comment: ok.Why can we suppose the existence of $w$?

Comment: what if I change the claim to If G is a $k$-edge connected graph and $v,v_1,v_2, \dots , v_k$ are $k+1$ vertices of $G$,then for $i$=$1,2...,k$, there exists  a $v-v_i$ path $P_i$ such that each path $P_i$ contains exactly one vertex ${v_1,v_2,...v_k}$ and for $i$ doesn't equal to$ j$ .$P_i$ and $P_j$ are edge disjoint .Is it valid ?

Comment: How would you suggest to do that?